# How to restart while loop in order to restart game?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I want the game to restart when the player pressed the `y` key on the keyboard after dying or getting hit by the small ball.

`BoxX` and `BoxY` are the coordinates for enemy balls

Ball holds the rectangle or hitbox for all the enemy balls

`ReverseX` and `Y`, `IndexX` and `Y`, and `BallXchange` and `Y` all have to do with the movement of the enemy balls.

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;


import java.io.File;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;



public class GameNotes extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
int x1=1;
int y1=1;

int ballx = 40;
int bally = 60;
boolean gameRunning = true;
BufferedImage image;
int windowx = 500;
int windowy = 500;
int score = 0;

int rectX = (int)(Math.random()*400)+30;
int rectY = (int)(Math.random()*400)+30;

int enemyX = (int)(Math.random()*300)+100;
int enemyY = (int)(Math.random()*250)+100;



int count = 1;
int num = 0;



boolean reverseX = false;
boolean reverseY = false;


boolean right = false;
boolean left = false;
boolean up = false;
boolean down = false;


 ArrayList<Integer> BoxX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 ArrayList<Integer> BoxY = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 ArrayList<Rectangle> Ball = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
 ArrayList<Integer> ReverseX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 ArrayList<Integer> ReverseY = new ArrayList<Integer>();


 ArrayList<Integer> BallYchange = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 ArrayList<Integer> BallXchange = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 ArrayList<Integer> indexY = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 ArrayList<Integer> indexX = new ArrayList<Integer>();


public GameNotes(){
    setFocusable(true);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GameDemo");
    frame.setSize(windowx, windowy);
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    addKeyListener(this);

    try{
     image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\10021707\\Desktop\\Game\\b.jpg"));
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("image not found \n E000384JW29400119482938WJDI39");
    }

    game:
    while(gameRunning){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(3);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("error");
}
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle (ballx,bally,20,20);
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle (rectX,rectY,30,30);
        Rectangle rE = new Rectangle (enemyX,enemyY,10,10);
        if(count == 1){
        BoxX.add(enemyX);
        BoxY.add(enemyY);
        Ball.add(rE);
        ReverseX.add(1);
        BallXchange.add(enemyX);
        num++;
        indexX.add(num);


        count--;
        }

        //System.out.println("ReverseY" + ReverseY.size());

        if(ballx >= 461)
            ballx = 461;

        if(ballx <= 0)
            ballx = 0;

        if(bally >= 432)
            bally = 432;

        if(bally <= 0)
            bally = 0;





        if(r.intersects(r2)){
            score+=5;

            rectX = (int)(Math.random()*400)+30;
            rectY = (int)(Math.random()*400)+30;

            enemyX = (int)(Math.random()*300)+50;
            enemyY = (int)(Math.random()*300)+50;


            BoxX.add(enemyX);
            BoxY.add(enemyY);


            int x = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;
            //System.out.println(x);
            if(x > 5){
                ReverseX.add(1);
                BallXchange.add(enemyX);
                num++;
                indexX.add(num);
            }


            if(x <= 5){
                ReverseY.add(1);
                BallYchange.add(enemyY);
                num++;
                indexY.add(num);
            }




            Rectangle En = new Rectangle (enemyX,enemyY,10,10);
            Ball.add(En);


            //System.out.println(Ball);

        }


            for(int i = 0; i < Ball.size(); i++){
                Rectangle w = new Rectangle (BoxX.get(i),BoxY.get(i),10,10);
                Ball.set(i,w);
            }



            for(int i = 0; i < BoxX.size(); i++){
                if(r.intersects(Ball.get(i))){
                    gameRunning = false;
                }
            }





            //System.out.println(ReverseY);

            for(int i = 0; i < ReverseX.size(); i++){
                BallXchange.set(i,BallXchange.get(i)+ReverseX.get(i));
                BoxX.set(indexX.get(i)-1,BallXchange.get(i));
                    if(BallXchange.get(i) >= 470 || BallXchange.get(i) <= 0){
                        ReverseX.set(i,ReverseX.get(i)*-1);
                    }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < ReverseY.size(); i++){
                BallYchange.set(i,BallYchange.get(i)+ReverseY.get(i));
                BoxY.set(indexY.get(i)-1,BallYchange.get(i));
                    if(BallYchange.get(i) >= 445 || BallYchange.get(i) <= 0){
                        ReverseY.set(i,ReverseY.get(i)*-1);
                    }
            }






        if(right)
            ballx++;
        if(left)
            ballx--;
        if(up)
            bally--;
        if(down)
            bally++;


        repaint();
    }
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
    g.fillOval(ballx,bally,20,20);
    g.fillRect(rectX,rectY,30,30);

    for(int i = 0; i < BoxX.size(); i++){
        g.fillOval(BoxX.get(i),BoxY.get(i),10,10);
    }

    if(!gameRunning){
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.clearRect(rectX,rectY,30,30);
        g.fillRect(rectX,rectY,30,30);
            for(int i = 0; i < BoxX.size(); i++){
                g.clearRect(BoxX.get(i),BoxY.get(i),10,10);
                g.fillOval(BoxX.get(i),BoxY.get(i),10,10);
                g.fillRect(BoxX.get(i),BoxY.get(i),10,10);
            }

        BoxX.clear();
        BoxY.clear();
        Ball.clear();
        ReverseX.clear();
        ReverseY.clear();
        BallXchange.clear();
        BallYchange.clear();
        indexX.clear();
        indexY.clear();

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        g.drawString("Game Over", 165, 200);
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        g.drawString("Do you want to play again?", 100, 230);
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        g.drawString("(y or n)", 200, 250);

    }

    if(gameRunning){
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 25));;
        g.drawString("Score: "+score, 100, 450);
    }

    /*for(int i = 0; i < Ball.size(); i++){
        g.fillRect((int)Ball.get(i).getX(),(int)Ball.get(i).getY(),10,10);
    }*/



}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        right = false;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        left = false;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        up = false;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        down = false;

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){


 int key = e.getKeyCode();

 if(gameRunning == false && key == e.VK_Y){
    score = 0;
    gameRunning = true;




 }



    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        right = true;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        left = true;




    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        up = true;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        down = true;


}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

}



public static void main (String [] samay){
    GameNotes test = new GameNotes();
}


}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A good idea would be to think about all the things that need to happen to start the game. Put this in a method like `restart`. Call that method when `y` is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ordonezalex suggested in his comment you can take the while loop and put it in a method such as this:

```
public void runGame() {

    while(gameRunning){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(3);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle (ballx,bally,20,20);
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle (rectX,rectY,30,30);
        Rectangle rE = new Rectangle (enemyX,enemyY,10,10);
        if(count == 1){
        BoxX.add(enemyX);
        BoxY.add(enemyY);
        Ball.add(rE);
        ReverseX.add(1);
        BallXchange.add(enemyX);
        num++;
        indexX.add(num);


        count--;
        }

        //System.out.println("ReverseY" + ReverseY.size());

        if(ballx >= 461)
            ballx = 461;

        if(ballx <= 0)
            ballx = 0;

        if(bally >= 432)
            bally = 432;

        if(bally <= 0)
            bally = 0;





        if(r.intersects(r2)){
            score+=5;

            rectX = (int)(Math.random()*400)+30;
            rectY = (int)(Math.random()*400)+30;

            enemyX = (int)(Math.random()*300)+50;
            enemyY = (int)(Math.random()*300)+50;


            BoxX.add(enemyX);
            BoxY.add(enemyY);


            int x = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;
            //System.out.println(x);
            if(x > 5){
                ReverseX.add(1);
                BallXchange.add(enemyX);
                num++;
                indexX.add(num);
            }


            if(x <= 5){
                ReverseY.add(1);
                BallYchange.add(enemyY);
                num++;
                indexY.add(num);
            }




            Rectangle En = new Rectangle (enemyX,enemyY,10,10);
            Ball.add(En);


            //System.out.println(Ball);

        }


            for(int i = 0; i < Ball.size(); i++){
                Rectangle w = new Rectangle (BoxX.get(i),BoxY.get(i),10,10);
                Ball.set(i,w);
            }



            for(int i = 0; i < BoxX.size(); i++){
                if(r.intersects(Ball.get(i))){
                    gameRunning = false;
                }
            }





            //System.out.println(ReverseY);

            for(int i = 0; i < ReverseX.size(); i++){
                BallXchange.set(i,BallXchange.get(i)+ReverseX.get(i));
                BoxX.set(indexX.get(i)-1,BallXchange.get(i));
                    if(BallXchange.get(i) >= 470 || BallXchange.get(i) <= 0){
                        ReverseX.set(i,ReverseX.get(i)*-1);
                    }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < ReverseY.size(); i++){
                BallYchange.set(i,BallYchange.get(i)+ReverseY.get(i));
                BoxY.set(indexY.get(i)-1,BallYchange.get(i));
                    if(BallYchange.get(i) >= 445 || BallYchange.get(i) <= 0){
                        ReverseY.set(i,ReverseY.get(i)*-1);
                    }
            }






        if(right)
            ballx++;
        if(left)
            ballx--;
        if(up)
            bally--;
        if(down)
            bally++;


        repaint();
    }
}
```

Then replace the while loop with this:

```
runGame();
```

And each time you want to re-run the game you can use that again, as long as the `boolean` gameRunning is true.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you would need to update in your code:

**A. Create a boolean called `programRunning` and set it to `true`:**

```
boolean gameRunning = true;
boolean programRunning = true;
```

**B. Create a private void method called `initGame()` and place all the game initialization code there:**

```
private void initGame()
{
    x1=1;
    y1=1;

    ballx = 40;
    bally = 60;
    windowx = 500;
    windowy = 500;
    score = 0;

    rectX = (int)(Math.random()*400)+30;
    rectY = (int)(Math.random()*400)+30;

    enemyX = (int)(Math.random()*300)+100;
    enemyY = (int)(Math.random()*250)+100;

    count = 1;
    num = 0;

    reverseX = false;
    reverseY = false;

    right = false;
    left = false;
    up = false;
    down = false;

    BoxX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    BoxY = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Ball = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    ReverseX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ReverseY = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    BallYchange = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    BallXchange = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    indexY = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    indexX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

**C. Modify the following code under the section where you are assigning a JPG to the `image` variable:**

```
try{
 image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\10021707\\Desktop\\Game\\b.jpg"));
}catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("image not found \n E000384JW29400119482938WJDI39");
}

//CODE CHANGED BELOW THIS COMMENT
do {
    initGame();
    while (gameRunning) {
        runGame();
    }
} while (programRunning);
```

**D. Create the `runGame()` method that contains all of your code within the `while (gameRunning)` loop:**

```
private void runGame()
{
    try{
        Thread.sleep(3);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("error");
}
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle (ballx,bally,20,20);
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle (rectX,rectY,30,30);
        Rectangle rE = new Rectangle (enemyX,enemyY,10,10);
        if(count == 1){
        BoxX.add(enemyX);
        BoxY.add(enemyY);
        Ball.add(rE);
        ReverseX.add(1);
        BallXchange.add(enemyX);
        num++;
        indexX.add(num);


        count--;
        }

        //System.out.println("ReverseY" + ReverseY.size());

        if(ballx >= 461)
            ballx = 461;

        if(ballx <= 0)
            ballx = 0;

        if(bally >= 432)
            bally = 432;

        if(bally <= 0)
            bally = 0;





        if(r.intersects(r2)){
            score+=5;

            rectX = (int)(Math.random()*400)+30;
            rectY = (int)(Math.random()*400)+30;

            enemyX = (int)(Math.random()*300)+50;
            enemyY = (int)(Math.random()*300)+50;


            BoxX.add(enemyX);
            BoxY.add(enemyY);


            int x = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;
            //System.out.println(x);
            if(x > 5){
                ReverseX.add(1);
                BallXchange.add(enemyX);
                num++;
                indexX.add(num);
            }


            if(x <= 5){
                ReverseY.add(1);
                BallYchange.add(enemyY);
                num++;
                indexY.add(num);
            }




            Rectangle En = new Rectangle (enemyX,enemyY,10,10);
            Ball.add(En);


            //System.out.println(Ball);

        }


            for(int i = 0; i < Ball.size(); i++){
                Rectangle w = new Rectangle (BoxX.get(i),BoxY.get(i),10,10);
                Ball.set(i,w);
            }



            for(int i = 0; i < BoxX.size(); i++){
                if(r.intersects(Ball.get(i))){
                    gameRunning = false;
                }
            }





            //System.out.println(ReverseY);

            for(int i = 0; i < ReverseX.size(); i++){
                BallXchange.set(i,BallXchange.get(i)+ReverseX.get(i));
                BoxX.set(indexX.get(i)-1,BallXchange.get(i));
                    if(BallXchange.get(i) >= 470 || BallXchange.get(i) <= 0){
                        ReverseX.set(i,ReverseX.get(i)*-1);
                    }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < ReverseY.size(); i++){
                BallYchange.set(i,BallYchange.get(i)+ReverseY.get(i));
                BoxY.set(indexY.get(i)-1,BallYchange.get(i));
                    if(BallYchange.get(i) >= 445 || BallYchange.get(i) <= 0){
                        ReverseY.set(i,ReverseY.get(i)*-1);
                    }
            }






        if(right)
            ballx++;
        if(left)
            ballx--;
        if(up)
            bally--;
        if(down)
            bally++;


        repaint();
    }
```

**E. Add this code to your `keyPressed(KeyEvent e)` method:**

```
if (gameRunning == false && key == KeyEvent.VK_N)
{
    programRunning = false;
    System.exit(0); //Closes the application.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just giving you the main idea :

```
do{
//All logic goes here

//At the end of the game take input from user in the form of 'Y|y' or 'N|n'

System.out.println("Do you want to continue : press 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no");  
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String choice=sc.nextLine();   
} while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
```